# RX ObserveOn issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I am new to RX and playing around with some samples, any ideas as to why the Console.writeLine in the Subscribe is not being invoked?

> var obs = Observable.Create(i =>
>               {
>
> ```
>               while(true)
>             {
>                 Thread.Sleep(250);
>
>                 i.OnNext(2.0);
>             }
>
>
>
>             return () => { };
>         })        
>         .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)   
>         .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
>         .Subscribe(i =>
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Inside Subscribe");
>         });
> ```

If I remove the

```
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
```

line all is fine?

Thanks

Comment: Well what *is* the current thread? And what are you doing to let the scheduler run its tasks on the current thread? Is this a console app?

Comment: The Current thread would be the thread the Subscribe is on, so Scheduler.TaskPool Thread. This is in a WPF app

Comment: `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` can get quite confusing - I highly suggest reading this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2009/11/21/observable-context-observable-subscribeon-and-observable-observeon.aspx

Comment: CurrentThread can't write on the  console since it's stuck in that infinite loop?

Comment: Dtex, you are correct- Current thread is stuck in that infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned, `SubscribeOn` and `ObserveOn` are not the best-named methods; I HIGHLY recommend reading this all the way through:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2009/11/21/observable-context-observable-subscribeon-and-observable-observeon.aspx

Basically, `SubscribeOn` tells the system what context to do the actual Subscribe/Unsubscribe wiring on, while `ObserveOn` tells the system what context to "execute as" when new values arrive in the source.

To start, allow me to tweak your example a bit:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start Thread ID:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
var subscription = Observable.Create<double>(i => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Observable thread ID:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pushing values from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(250);            
            i.OnNext(2.0);
        }
        return () => { };
    })        
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)   
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
    .Subscribe(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribable thread ID:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Subscribe");
    });    
Console.ReadLine();
subscription.Dispose();
```

If you run this, you'll see something like:

```
Start Thread ID:21
Observable thread ID:23
Pushing values from thread 23
Pushing values from thread 23
Pushing values from thread 23
Pushing values from thread 23
```

Now let's swap the threads we `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn`:

```
.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)   
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)
```

Now we get:

```
Start Thread ID:26
Observable thread ID:26
Pushing values from thread 26
Pushing values from thread 26
Subscribable thread ID:27
Inside Subscribe
Pushing values from thread 26
Subscribable thread ID:27
Inside Subscribe
Pushing values from thread 26
Subscribable thread ID:27
Inside Subscribe
```